# Change resource route name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hou could I change resource name without changing resource URL.

**Explanation:**

My resource route is `resources :universities`

So my routes are `new_university_path` or `universities_path`

Now I have changed my resource name to departments as follows:

```
resources :departments, :controller => :universities
```

But problem is when I run rake routes I found that my URL has already been changed. So I like a solution where after changing my resource name my routes are works as before, like `new_university_path` or `universities_path`

Is this possible in rails 3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add:

```
resources :departments, :controller => :universities, :as => :universities
```

That should keep the URL helpers the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that by using [naming routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes) by giving it the name you want for that route in `:as` option:

```
resources :departments, :controller => :universities, :as => :universities
```